# Solve the integral in the expression $x(t) = e^{-kt} \int e^{kt} k \cos(t/2)dt$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

I'm following the course MIT 18.03. In [this problem][1], we evaluate the following expression containing an integral:
$$
x(t) = e^{-kt} \int e^{kt} k \cos(t/2)dt\tag{1}
$$
which finally gives:
$$
x(t) = \frac{2k \sin(t/2)+ 4k^2\cos(t/2)}{1+4k^2}+ce^{-kt}\tag{2}
$$
One possibility would be to make a substitution $u = \sin(x)$, but more than that I'm stuck

**Edit** (with the help of the comments)

So we can use the following substitutions:

\begin{align}
u &= \cos(t/2)\tag{3}\\
\implies u' &= 1/2\sin(t/2)\tag{4}\\
v'&= e^{kt}\tag{5}\\
\implies v &= \frac{1}{k} e^{kt}\tag{6}\\
\end{align}

Now using integration by part we can write

\begin{align}
\int v'u &= vu - \int vu'\tag{7}\\
&=\cos(t/2) \cdot \frac{1}{k}e^{kt} - \int \frac{1}{k}e^{kt}\frac{1}{2}\sin (t/2)\tag{8}\\
\end{align}
[1]: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-i-first-order-differential-equations/solution-by-integrating-factors/MIT18_03SCF11_rec_04s5_sol.pdf

Comment: Integrate by parts $u = \cos(t/2), v' = e^{kt}$. What is the $\omega$ supposed to be doing?

Comment: By far the easiest way to integrate $\int e^{at}\cos bt\;dt$ or $\int e^{at}\sin bt\;dt$ is to integrate $\int e^{(a+ib)t}\; dt$ and then take the real or imaginary part.

Comment: sorry @mattos. $\omega$ is here meaningless. I removed it

Comment: So did the subsitution and tried to use integration by part. (and do not want to atke real or imaginary part as it not the strategy proposed in the exercice). But I'm still stuck. What am I doing wrong? @mattos ? I labelled the equation, so it is easier to point the problematic ones

Comment: I know I'm gonna come across as rather cranky and this has little to do with solving this...but when it comes to differential equations everyone seems to use such tortured notation here. Isn't this really e.g., $x(t) = e^{-kt}\int^t_{C} k e^{ku} \cos(u/2) du$? The variable $t$ in the original statement of the problem seems overloaded. Again I know I'm criticizing established convention here.

Answer (score 3):

To do it faster, consider
$$I =  \int e^{kt}  e^{\frac{i t}{2}}\,dt=\int e^{\left(k+\frac{i}{2}\right) t } \,dt=\frac{2 }{2 k+i}e^{\left(k+\frac{i}{2}\right) t}$$ Now, rewrite the rhs as
$$\frac{2 (2k-i)}{(2 k+i)(2k-i)}e^{k t}e^{\frac{i}{2} t}=\frac{4k-2i}{4k^2+1}\,e^{k t}\, \left(\cos
   \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)+i \sin \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\right)$$

Expand to isolate the real and imaginary parts to get
$$\Re(I)=\int e^{k t} \cos \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\,dt=\frac{2 e^{k t} \left(2 k \cos \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)+\sin
   \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\right)}{4 k^2+1}+C$$
$$\Im(I)=\int e^{k t} \sin \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\,dt=\frac{2 e^{k t} \left(2 k \sin \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)-\cos
   \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\right)}{4 k^2+1}+C$$

Now, just multiply $\Re(I)$ by $k \,e^{-kt}$ to obtain $x(t)$.

If you think about it, no need of integration by parts. The only think I used is that
$$\int e^{ax} \,dx=\frac 1 a  e^{ax} $$

Answer (score 2):

Observe the following by Integration By Parts:
\begin{align*}
x(t) &= ke^{-kt} \int e^{kt}\cos\left ( \frac{t}{2} \right ) \, \mathrm{d}t\\
&= ke^{-kt} \left [2e^{kt}\sin\left ( \frac{t}{2} \right ) - 2k\int e^{kt}\sin\left ( \frac{t}{2} \right ) \, \mathrm{d}t \right ] && \text{using } u=e^{kt}, v'=\cos\left (\frac{t}{2} \right )\\
&= ke^{-kt} \left [2e^{kt}\sin\left ( \frac{t}{2} \right ) + 4ke^{kt}\cos\left ( \frac{t}{2} \right ) - 4k^2 \int e^{kt}\cos\left ( \frac{t}{2} \right ) \, \mathrm{d}t \right ] && \text{using } u=e^{kt}, v'=\sin\left (\frac{t}{2} \right )\\
&= 2k\sin\left ( \frac{t}{2} \right ) + 4k^2\cos\left ( \frac{t}{2} \right ) - 4k^2 x(t) + Ce^{-kt}\\
&= \frac{2k \sin\left ( \frac{t}{2} \right ) + 4k^2 \cos\left ( \frac{t}{2} \right )}{1 + 4k^2}+ ce^{-kt}
\end{align*}
and the result follows.

Answer (score 2):

From part c: "... a consequence, you may recall, of two integrations by parts..."  So we expect we can integrate (or differentiate) the cosine piece twice to get a simple multiple of the integral with which we start.

By factoring out the $k$ from your integral, let
$$  I = \int \mathrm{e}^{kt} \cos(t/2) \,\mathrm{d}t  \text{.}  $$
Taking $u_1 = \cos(t/2)$ so $\mathrm{d}u_1 = (-1/2) \sin(t/2) \,\mathrm{d}t$ and $\mathrm{d}v_1 = \mathrm{e}^{kt} \,\mathrm{d}t$ so $v_1 = (1/k) \mathrm{e}^{kt}$, we obtain
$$  I = \frac{1}{k} \mathrm{e}^{kt} \cos(t/2) + \frac{1}{2k} \int \mathrm{e}^{kt} \sin(t/2) \,\mathrm{d}t  \text{.}  $$
Taking $u_2 = \sin(t/2)$ so $\mathrm{d}u_2 = (1/2) \cos(t/2) \,\mathrm{d}t$ and $\mathrm{d}v_2 = \mathrm{e}^{kt} \,\mathrm{d}t$ so $v_2 = (1/k)\mathrm{e}^{kt}$, we obtain
$$  I = \frac{1}{k} \mathrm{e}^{kt} \cos(t/2) + \frac{1}{2k} \left( \frac{1}{k} \mathrm{e}^{kt} \sin(t/2) - \frac{1}{2k} \int \mathrm{e}^{kt} \cos(t/2) \,\mathrm{d}t \right)  \text{.}  $$
Notice that the remaining integral is $I$.  So we have
\begin{align*}
I &= \frac{1}{k} \mathrm{e}^{kt} \cos(t/2) +  \frac{1}{2k^2} \mathrm{e}^{kt} \sin(t/2) - \frac{1}{4k^2} I + C \\
I + \frac{1}{4k^2} I &= \frac{1}{k^2} \mathrm{e}^{kt} \left( k\cos(t/2) + \frac{1}{2} \sin(t/2) \right) + C  \\
I &= \frac{1}{k\left(1 + \frac{1}{4k^2}\right)} \mathrm{e}^{kt} \left( k \cos(t/2) + \frac{1}{2} \sin(t/2) \right) + C  \\
    &= \frac{4k}{\left(4k^2 + 1\right)} \mathrm{e}^{kt} \left( k \cos(t/2) + \frac{1}{2} \sin(t/2) \right) + C
\end{align*}
... and you should be able to finish from here.

Comment: many thanks for your great answer @EricTowers. However I have a question: in the third last question there is a $k^2$ in the denominator. How come does it become $k$ in the second last equation (and not $k^2$?

Comment: @ecjb : Before the words "Notice ...", we have $1/(2k)$ outside the big parentheses and on the interior terms $1/k$ and $1/(2k)$, respectively, so we get $k^2$s.

Answer (score 2):

Integrating by parts twice is an obvious way to handle this integral.  Another approach is to write $\cos t/2= \frac{1}{2} (e^{it/2}+ e^{-it/2})$ so the integral becomes

$$\begin{align} k \int e^{kt} \cos t/2 \, dt = &\frac{k}{2} \int  \left(e^{t(k+i/2)}+ e^{t(k-i/2)}\right)\, dt \\= &\frac{k}{2} \left( \frac{e^{t(k+i/2)}}{k+i/2} + \frac{e^{t(k-i/2)}}{k-i/2}\right) + \text{const.}\\= &\frac{k^2e^{tk}}{k^2+1/4}\left(\cos t/2 + \frac{1}{2k} \sin t/2\right)+\text{const.}\end{align}$$
and
$$x(t) = \frac{k^2}{k^2+1/4}\left(\cos t/2 + \frac{1}{2k} \sin t/2\right)+ c \,e^{-kt},$$ where $c$ is a constant.

Comment: thanks for your answer @mjw. If I develop the second equation, I get $= \frac{ke^{kt}}{2(k^2+1/4)} \left( e^{i/2}+ e^{-i/2}\right) + \text{const}\\$. Is it correct? If yes, how can I get from there to the third one?

Comment: Should be $\frac{ke^{kt}}{2(k^2+1/4)}\left( (k+\frac{1}{2i} )e^{it/2}+ (k-\frac{1}{2i})e^{-it/2} )\right)+ \text{const.}$

Comment: Now use $\cos t/2 = \frac{1}{2} (e^{it/2}+e^{-it/2})$ and $\sin t/2 = \frac{1}{2i}  (e^{it/2}-e^{-it/2})$.